# How to crawl a site that redirects to "/"

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy to crawl several websites. My spider isn't allowed to jump across domains. In this scenario, redirects make the crawler stop immediately. In most cases I know how to handle it, but this is a weird one.

The culprit is: http://www.cantonsd.org/

I checked its redirect pattern with http://www.wheregoes.com/ and it tells me it redirects to "/". This prevents the spider to enter its `parse` function. How can I handle this?

EDIT:
The code.

I invoke the spider using the APIs provided by scrapy here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script
The only difference is that my spider is custom. It is created as follows:

```
spider = DomainSimpleSpider(
   start_urls = [start_url],
   allowed_domains = [allowed_domain],
   url_id = url_id,
   cur_state = cur_state,
   state_id_url_map = id_url,
   allow = re.compile(r".*%s.*" % re.escape(allowed_path), re.IGNORECASE),
   tags = ('a', 'area', 'frame'),
   attrs = ('href', 'src'),
   response_type_whitelist = [r"text/html", r"application/xhtml+xml", r"application/xml"],
   state_abbr = state_abbrs[cur_state]
)
```

I think the problem is that the `allowed_domains` sees that `/` is not part of the list (which contains only `cantonsd.org`) and shuts down everything.

I'm not reporting the full spider code because it is not invoked at all, so it can't be the problem.

Comment: And do you have permission to scrape them? Because it seems like you are the culprit here.

Comment: Show the code you have currently.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul if I do not have the permission they'd specify it in their robots.txt, which I respect. They specify that they do not want more than a request per second and in fact I am making a request every two seconds.

Comment: @Mikk You need explicit permission to scrape someone, not assume that you are free to do so unless someone yells back at you. Data on that website doesn't belong to you, and in no place they've allowed you to acquire and process them.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I understand the logic but I have two objections. First, they are not yelling back at me. This is a technical problem, not a moral one. Second, according to this logic, no search engine could exist. Do you thing Google or Yahoo asked explicit permission to every single website? Data on that website do not belong to them...

Comment: @Mikk my moral, and legal, objections here are good enough for me to downvote and note help you. And those massive websites have a simple opt-out option, available easily to any website owner and are also very open about who and when they scrape. You don't.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Yes I have. I respect robots.txt, any specification under a very big list of user agents.

Comment: This is just a freak site.  The 302 status code and the `Location: /` header seem completely spurious because they serve the actual page contents to you after all anyway.  I would just put this down as one of those many sites which break themselves in ways which do not need to be solved.